# How do filter plans with or without trial on Stripe with Laravel 5?

Tags: php, api, laravel, stripe.net

I want to retrieve this.
all plan.
all plan without Trial Day.
all plan only trial day.
but i don't know the procedure for take a filter on api Stripe.
https://stripe.com/docs/api#plans

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Stripe\Plan;
use Stripe\Stripe;

class PlanController extends Controller {

    public function index(Request $request) 
    {
        Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
        $param = ['limit' => 20]; 
        $opt = ['livemode' => false];

        $plans = Plan::all($param,$opt);

        return plans;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you fetch all, you can filter it through php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Stripe\Plan;
use Stripe\Stripe;

class PlanController extends Controller {

    public function index(Request $request) 
    {
        Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
        $param = ['limit' => 20]; 
        $opt = ['livemode' => false];

        $all_plans = Plan::all($param,$opt);
        $trial_plans = [];
        $no_trial_plans = []

        foreach ($all_plans['data'] as $plan) {
            if ($plan['trial_period_days'] == null) {
                $no_trial_plans[] = $plan;
            }
            else {
                $trial_plans[] = $plan;
            }
        }

        return [$all_plans, $trial_plans, $no_trial_plans];
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this is a way but do i filter on stripe api as with the $param? 

-> retrieve all plan without trial
plan::all('trial': false);
-> retrieve all trial plan
plan::all('onlytrial': true);
-> retrieve all where meta-data is like
plan::all('meta': ['like' => 'FR']);

Comment: did you try call Plan::all(['limit' => 20],['trial_period_days'=>null]); ?

Comment: good, i found for only trial 30 days => $param = ['limit' => 20,'trial_period_days' => 30]; and for all without trial $param = ['limit' => 20,'trial_period_days' => 0]; thanks for your help